# Exception when getting CGColor from UIColor in iOS

Tags: ios, uicolor

I am trying to create custom buttons for my views. Everything works well except when rendering I am getting an exception being thrown regarding my colors. My class has 2 color properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor* defaultBackground;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor* clickedBackground;
```

One to represent the default rendering color and the other for when the user has it clicked. Inside my initWithFrame method I initialize the colors:

```
defaultBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
clickedBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

This is all well and good until I get to the rendering where it throws an exception when getting the CGColor:

```
if((self.state & UIControlStateHighlighted) == 0)
    {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, defaultBackground.CGColor); //Crashes on this line
        ...
```

Here is the exception that I am getting:

```
2012-04-13 10:19:51.005 -[__NSMallocBlock__ CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d94d20
2012-04-13 10:19:51.072 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d94d20'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a memory problem? Because `[UIColor colorWith...]` is autoreleased. Is `defaultBackground` a instance variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the two lines in your `initWithFrame:` as follows:

```
self.defaultBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
self.clickedBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

The problem is that assigning an autoreleased `UIColor` object directly to an ivar results in a dangling pointer to a released object. An alternative is:

```
defaultBackground = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
clickedBackground = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: This worked out for me. I still have moments where I lose track between the differences of ivars and 'self'. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do -

```
self.defaultBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
self.clickedBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

...otherwise they're not being retained.